# Reading json response with .@. fails in feature file

Tags: karate

This is my response.

`

```
 { 
"Response": {
"_": {
  "QueryResponse": {
    "_": null,
    "@": {
      "totalCount": "55"
    }
  }
},
"@": {
  "time": "2020-12-22T18:21:58.862-08:00"
}
}
}
```

`

I am doing this in feature file

`* print "total count="+ result.session.runtimeData.read_count.Response._.QueryResponse.@.totalCount`

and getting
`<eval>:1:78 Expected ident but found error result.session.runtimeData.read_taxcode_count.Response._.QueryResponse.@.totalCount ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 78`

^ points to @

tried enclosing it in [''] many places for the response but  I am not able to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you don't need to complicate things, try this:

```
* def count = get[0] response..totalCount
```

Also this would have worked:

```
* def count = response.Response._.QueryResponse['@'].totalCount
```